# How to create special layout folder for galaxy Note 8?

Tags: android, android-layout, galaxy

I have a layout folder for galaxy note 2 named **layout-large-xhdpi-1280x800**. Now I want to create a layout for Galaxy note 8 that is larger (8in). Which folder layout should I create?

I have tested **layout-xlarge-xhdpi-1280x800**. but it is ignored and the layout in **layout-large-xhdpi-1280x800** is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem can be fixed using changing layout folder name to **tvdpi**.

Try using **tvdpi**, like Nexus 7

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used **layout-large-land-tvdpi-1280x800** for Galaxy note 8 and worked